# How to format jinja tables

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I have a table that I am trying to display a table properly on a flask HTML site.

my python file is

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def LoadTest():
    global USERS,STARTTIME,ENDTIME,SUBTYPE,SUBSTATUS,USAGE
    CollectValues()
    titles = ['USERS','STARTTIME','ENDTIME','SUBTYPE','SUBSTATUS','USAGE']
    return render_template('Test.html', data1 = USERS , data2 = STARTTIME ,titles = titles)
```

My current html code is

```
  <table>
{% for item in titles %}
   <th class="c1">{{item}}</th>
{% endfor %}
{% for dater in data1 %}
  <tr><td class="c2">{{dater}}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}

{% for dater2 in data2 %}
<tr><td>{{dater2}}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

However, this outputs the table as

```
USERS   STARTTIME   ENDTIME     SUBTYPE     SUBSTATUS   USAGE
cody
mimic
james
7/10/2020
7/11/2020
7/12/2020
```

I am trying to format the table like this

```
USERS   STARTTIME   ENDTIME     SUBTYPE     SUBSTATUS   USAGE
cody    7/10/2020   8/10/2020   Premium     Active       15GB
mimic   7/11/2020   8/11/2020   Premium     Active       15GB
James   7/12/2020   8/12/2020   Premium+    Active       25GB
```

All of the Table content meant to go below the Table headers are in lists. I have a list for Users, Starttime, Endtime, Subtype, Substatus, And Usage. I am having difficulty getting this properly formatted. I keep coming back to the issue of them stacking.

Comment: Can you please give more code for your route. It is difficult to see how the data belong together. Do USERS and STARTTIME belong to the same data record or are they additional data records?

Comment: @Detlef I updated the post to show the route. The USER , STARTTIME , etc. lists are just parsed from a txt file im using as a scuffed database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should solve your problem.

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def load_test():
  global USERS,STARTTIME,ENDTIME,SUBTYPE,SUBSTATUS,USAGE
  CollectValues()
  titles = ['USERS','STARTTIME','ENDTIME','SUBTYPE','SUBSTATUS','USAGE']
  dataset = zip(USERS, STARTTIME, ENDTIME, SUBTYPE, SUBSTATUS, USAGE)
  return render_template('test.html', titles=titles, data=dataset)
```

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    {% for item in titles %}
      <th class="c1">{{item}}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for user, starttime, endtime, subtype, subsstatus, usage in data %}
    <tr>
      <td class="c2">{{user}}</td>
      <td class="c2">{{starttime}}</td>
      <td class="c2">{{endtime}}</td>
      <td class="c2">{{subtype}}</td>
      <td class="c2">{{substatus}}</td>
      <td class="c2">{{usage}}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that's closer. It's still stacking the lists under the first collum though

Comment: This is my current HTML for the test page. It still has the stacking issue, I believe everything is setup correctly. 
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Simple tables</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
      {% for item in titles %}
        <th class="c1">{{item}}</th>
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in data %}
      <tr><td class="c2">{{item}}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Sorry my mistake, will revise my answer.